# Community Promotion Ad Design

Tags: discussion

To help advertise the site, we should have one or more banners for the StackExchange Community Promotion Ads. For anyone not familiar with them, these are basically ads that we get to place on other StackExchange sites for free (as long as there is enough community support on the target community). For an example of one of these threads, [look at the 2014 Electrical Engineering ad page](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3240/community-promotion-ads-2014).

What we need is one or more images that are self-contained ads that (hopefully) entice people to click on a link back to ham.se. Once these are done, then we can post them and hopefully increase the traffic to the site. Post anything that sounds good, and then we can see if we can make it into an ad!

Answer (score 4):

I loved the space.se sample that was there, here's a twist on that.

Obviously wording could be changed. Also, if anyone has any ideas but can't put them down visually, let me know and I can help create it.

[image: ham.se]

Comment: The only thing I have against this design is it is not obvious to someone who is a ham what this site is about. Maybe "Ham Radio" would be better.

Comment: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3712/638

Comment: Could you make a “source” file for this image available (that is, something more editable)?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I've been away for a while. I'm not sure I have the source anymore but I can whip it up again very quickly. What program would you like it in, and any changes I can make for you too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very creative in terms of wording, but one idea I had was to use a Smith chart as a background, and draw a question mark on it (as if using the Smith chart). Below is the raw image that could be used as a basis for an ad. Below are some catch-lines that I thought were *OK* but not *great*.

- Looking for a good match?
- Got bad reflections?

[image]